# Is the Reedy model structure cofibrantly generated?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

I am reading about the Reedy model structure from [Hovey's](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/hovey-model-cats.pdf) book and

> I was wondering if the Reedy model structure on $\mathcal{M}^{\Delta}$
> is cofibrantly generated by a small set of arrows and permits the
> small object argument.

I see that in theorem 5.2.5 he proves the existence of a functorial factorization by transfinite induction assuming functorial factorization on $\mathcal{M},$ so there would not be any need to apply the SOA, but I am still left wondering if the Reedy model structure can be seen as cofibrantly generated. Is there any reference for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At minimum, I guess you're assuming that $\mathcal M$ itself is cofibrantly generated as a hypothesis?

Comment: Yes. I thought that if $\mathcal{M}$ is cofibrantly generated by $\mathcal{J}$ then $\mathcal{M}^{\Delta}$ would be cofibrantly generated by the set of maps $X\to Y$ such that $X_i \bigsqcup_{L_iX}L_iY \to Y_i \in \mathcal{J}$ for every $i \in \Delta$ but I am not sure how to prove this.

Comment: The answer is yes: see Thm 15.6.27 in Hirschhorn's book *Model categories and their localizations*.

Comment: perfect! thanks very much for the precise reference.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski Maybe post that as an answer?